# data argument not used by format string in iOS

Tags: ios

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"www.bikrionline.com/database/iqry_mbr_mst.php"];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"txtemail=%@&txtpwd=%@&txtcpwd", email, password,confirmpassword];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[_webView loadRequest: request];
```

Comment: So is there a question here?  Follow this guidance:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed the format specifier  try using this

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"txtemail=%@&txtpwd=%@&txtcpwd=%@", email, password,confirmpassword];
```

Comment: what is difference between your answer and mine?

Comment: no difference is there na.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string only has 2 format specifiers but you are passing 3 arguments. Make them match.

Check this :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"txtemail=%@&txtpwd=%@&txtcpwd=%@", email, password,confirmpassword];
```

Comment: how can i check that one in safari

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. You have missed format specifier`(%@)` for confirm passord.

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"txtemail=%@&txtpwd=%@&txtcpwd=%@", email, password,confirmpassword];
```

**Update:** Try url with `http://`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.bikrionline.com/database/iqry_mbr_mst.php"];
```

Check this also..

```
UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
[self.view addSubView:webView];
```

Comment: in that UIVIEW may not respond to load Request at webview

Comment: Manually check your url in safari whether it is work or not?

Comment: i am a fresher how can i check that one in safari

Comment: i did missed that one

Comment: that issue cleared but at the load request it shows an issue like this "UIView may not respond to load request

Comment: did you add your webview to your baseview.. as `UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
[self.view addSubView:webView];`

Comment: ya now its working thank you very much mani

Comment: If it is useful to you, accept my answer by tick which will be take attention for future visitors :) I've updated my answer...

Comment: i want to check my url in safari plase send me the format for that one.

Comment: I think, you cann't check POST type url in safari. You can try with RestClient in firebox.

Comment: ok how can i do that one. plase send me the process

Comment: sorry it's not working. so my php developer also new one. so how to send the request. plase explain that one dude.

Comment: Go ahead with your work. good luck :)

Comment: at least give any tutorial for that na.

Comment: see this url https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/restclient-tool/